# ie 9 cros domain window.open postMessage no such interface supported

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, popupwindow

I want to open a popup to a different domain and send a message to it using postMessage

the code runs at https://local_domain.test

```
var popupObj=window.open("https://different_domain.test/do.php", '', .....);
popupObj.postMessage("some text", "https://different_domain.test");  //other local domain for server
```

it works on chrome and firefox but not on ie9
I get "No such interface supported" on the line of popupObj.postMessage

of course the receiving domain has the needed code :
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false); ......

Answer (score 1):

IE9 has only partial support for `postMessage`: in IE9 you can use postMessage only from within iframe or frames, not from other windows, or tabs. This means that popups in particular are not supported.

For details see: http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage

As a workaround you can try some of the [polyfills available for postMessage](http://html5polyfill.com/#postmessage).

Comment: Yes you can try if you can use some of the polyfills that are available. Check the edit.